# Cannot call value of non-function type 'Closure Name'

Tags: swift, closures

I define a Closure named `touchBlock`, and user it in `override func touchesEnded`, then I get an error :

> Cannot call value of non-function type '((ELControl, UIEvent, UIEvent)
>   -> Void?)?

Here is my code:

```
var touchBlock: ((_ view: ELControl, _ touches: UIEvent, _ event: UIEvent) -> Void?)?    
override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    if self.touchBlock != nil {

        self.touchBlock(nil, touches, event)
    } else {

        super.touchesEnded(touches, with: event)
    }
}
```

Please help me to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to unwrap the optional

```
self.touchBlock!(nil, touches, event)
```

or preferable with optional binding

```
if let block = self.touchBlock {
   block(nil, touches, event) ...
```

But consider that the passed arguments don't match the types of the closure at all (`view` and `event` are non-optional and the type of `touches` is completely different).

Comment: 1) try to avoid explicit unwrapping of optionals - as it's likely crash you application in case of variable that designed to occasionally be `nil` is `nil` 2) optionals chaining provides better way of expressing what is stated as a "preferable way"

Comment: Optional chaining is perfect stand-alone but in this case the preceding check has revealed that the block does have a value and can be 100% safely unwrapped.

Answer (score 0):

You need to unwrap your closure variable first. You can use optional chaining syntax for instance(pay attention to question mark `?` appeared right after `self.touchBlock` inside the `if statement`)

```
var touchBlock: ((_ view: ELControl, _ touches: UIEvent, _ event: UIEvent) -> Void?)?    
override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    if self.touchBlock != nil {

        self.touchBlock?(nil, touches, event)
    } else {

        super.touchesEnded(touches, with: event)
    }
}
```

Comment: Optional chaining is actually pointless because you just checked that `touchBlock` is not `nil`.

Comment: don't agree with you. it's equal with `if let ...` unwrapping and block innovating then. and even better as provides shorter, better readable syntax.

Comment: Yes but you are checking **twice**, first object != `nil` and then with optional chaining which is redundant.

Comment: ought to accept, in case there is `else` branch, `if let` syntax works probably the best. but this variant still possible. the idea of variable unwrapping is crucial the way question is asked

Answer (score 0):

**There are 2 cases which needs to handled in your code.**

```
var touchBlock: ((_ view: ELControl, _ touches: UIEvent, _ event: UIEvent) -> Void?)?
```

Your block definition shows that you can only pass non-nil values to the block and even your block is optional. So as **@Igor** suggested you should call the block as:

```
self.touchBlock?(<non-nil-value>, touches, event)
```

Here, `?` mark with block, will handle optional block condition.

But if you want some other operation if block is nil. Then you can use **if-let** condition for that:

```
if let block = self.touchBlock {
    block(<non-nil-value>, touches, event)
} else {
    super.touchesEnded(touches, with: event)
}
```

**But, if you want to pass nil value as well, define you block as:**

// Set `ELControl` view as `optional` with `?` mark

```
var touchBlock: ((_ view: ELControl?, _ touches: UIEvent, _ event: UIEvent) -> Void?)?
```

and call:

```
if let block = self.touchBlock {
    block(nil, touches, event)
} else {
    super.touchesEnded(touches, with: event)
}
```